# change ratio exercise

Tags: derivatives, change-of-variable

A parachutist is launched from an airplane that goes from West to East at $3,000$ m. A child, who at the moment of launching the parachutist is located $500$ m east of the plane (horizontal distance), runs to meet him at a speed of $5$m / s. Assuming that the parachutist falls vertically at a speed of $100$m / s and that the child begins to run at the same moment that the parachutist is released, determine; The distance (diagonal) between the child and the parachutist after 10 s With what speed do they approach each other at that moment ($10$s)?

Comment: Hi and welcome to math.SE. You're more likely to be well received if you show us your efforts and attempts, instead of merely stating your question.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

After $10$ seconds

- the parachutist is at $H=2000$ m of height
- the chidren is $L=450$ m from the vertical projection of the starting point of the parachutist

then we can use Pythagorean theorem to find $D$.

For the speed let use the same method to find the distance $D(t)$ as a function of the time.